# QT Creator connection in WIndows Azure Storage

Tags: qt, ubuntu-12.04, blobstorage

Good day. I am newbie to QT Programming in Ubuntu and currently, i am stack with the connection in Windows Azure Storage using QT Creator. How to deal with this problem? How to Set up a connection between Windows Azure storage and QT Creator. Please help me. I want to get rid of this problem. Thanks alot.